# Install Xubuntu to SD card via USB memory stick

Tags: boot, usb, xubuntu

I would like to install Xubuntu. I have a 2 Gb USB stick and it works fine every time I try Xubuntu in live mode.
My plan is to install it on an SD card with 32 Gb capacity.

I do not want to do partitioning on my current hard disk, I am not the only user of the computer. We have no external or portable hard disk.

I will try Xubuntu in live mode and install it on the SD card without modifying any portion of the current hard disk (now with Windows 7).

Will my plan work? I do not know if it will affect any content on our Windows 7 or any portion of the boot manager.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This can be done provided you proceed with caution. The grub bootloader doesn't have to be installed on the same drive as your Windows installation.  I do similar things with USB sticks often. If your BIOS supports booting from SDcard it's a standard installation, if not, there's a tutorial on how to do exactly what you have in mind [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootFromSD)

Answer (score -1):

That is not a very good idea.. Once you install any version of Ubuntu or Xubuntu, it creates and manages the GRUB loader, which stores all the information about the booting point of both Windows and your current distro. If anything should go wrong, you might have to repair Windows for recovering the bootloader for Windows.

Comment: Just a bit of research on your part would have changed this answer to something useful.